# On 「～ようってんじゃない」

Tags: abbreviations

As in a line from the TV drama 「[高校教師](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E7%A6%81%E6%96%AD%E3%81%AE%E6%84%9B%E3%81%A8%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB/dp/B00FNG28N8)」 ep1 (00:04:41):

> 今朝のこと、担任に告げ**ようってんじゃない**よ！

Or a line from a Japanese version of 「[Demian](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=aRfkAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT21&lpg=PT21&dq=%E2%80%9D%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=wmZqVIixJ4&sig=m9XTOlZvZZD3PR9mruRqJMGhAyA&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmgYbW9rfTAhUGopQKHUNNAjcQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9D%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E2%80%9D&f=false)」:

> おれはなにもお前を、困らせ**ようってんじゃない**。

Is it simply an abbreviation of 「**よう**と思**ってんじゃない**」?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost!

> 「～～ようってんじゃない」＝「～～ようと言ってるんじゃない」

In the examples you have listed, however, it is actually pretty close to 「思ってる」 in meaning.

Seems you have already noticed that, in Japanese, the line between 「言う」 and 「思う」 is often blurry.